# Why I can't get the input value in my web service?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to get my input value (which I posted to my restful web service using $http.post, AngularJS) using @POST, JAXB 
Here is my java code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public StackDTO setNour(.....,
        @QueryParam("stack") String stack)
{
    System.out.println("nour call post");
    StackDTO json = new StackDTO();
    json.setStack(stack);
    return json;
}
```

In the StackDTO class, I have:

```
String stack;
....
public String getStack() {
    return stack;
}

public void setStack(String stack) {
    stack = stack;
}
```

I didn't get an error, post method is working since in the console , I got the call "nour call post"[image]

Why I can't get the input value in my web service?

```js
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   // or  'Content-Type':'application/json'
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

```html
<form ng-submit="save()">
      <input ng-model="stack"></input>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-:

```
     String stack;
      ....
     public String getStack() {
     return stack;
      }

   public void setStack(String stack) {
    this.stack = stack;
 }
```

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: Where are saving the response of the POST method . There should be an error in printing that response

Comment: I will edit my question and add my html and js code. post edited.